# full uninstall/remove of Windows printer driver - automation

Tags: windows, printing, driver, uninstallation, printers

what is the correct way of full uninstall of the Windows printer driver?

I need to automate this process. For now I perform list of actions which requires one of even two rebooting:

1. pnputil -e
   choose needed inf and run
   pnputil -f -d
2. clean registry:

   in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print

clean

```
Environments\<depending on OS>\Drivers\Version-3\<My Print>
Forms\<My Forms>
Monitors\<My monitor>
Printers\<My printer>
```

3.delete dll, gpd, inf files in c:\windows (it is possible only after rebooting)

I know that it is different process in WinXP and Win7/Win8. More important for me is Win 7 & Win 8.

I believe should be another way for doing it. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall driver using functionality provided by PrintUI.dll by running command (cmd):

```
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /dd /m "Your Driver Name"
```

It is builtin functionality in Win XP, Vista, 7, 8. This will remove your registry data + files from windows folder independently on windows version you are executing on.